# The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMotionUsageDescription key

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting the following error during the runtime:

This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMotionUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I have added the key to the plist file:

```
<!--  Motion -->
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs to be able to access your motion use</string>
```

and this the code in AppDelegate:

```
if ([CMMotionActivityManager isActivityAvailable])
{
    CMMotionActivityManager *motionManager = [[CMMotionActivityManager alloc] init];
    NSOperationQueue *motionActivityQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [motionManager queryActivityStartingFromDate:[NSDate distantPast] toDate:[NSDate date] toQueue:motionActivityQueue withHandler:^(NSArray *activities, NSError *error) {
        if (error && (error.domain == CMErrorDomain) && (error.code == CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized)) {

        } else if (activities || !error) {

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        });
    }];        
}
```

Why am I keep getting this crash? I deleted all the derived folder, cleaned the project. But still asking me the key! Is it an Apple bug?

Comment: Common mistake: there are usually 3 .plist files. Add this key only in the first one and not in the .plst file under Tests group.

Comment: @sharadchauhan thank you for your comment. Project settings -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist file: xxx.plist. I added the key to this one. What do you mean by saying the first one?

Comment: if you search you project on bottom-left side with search string .plist you get 3 .plist, I thought this may be the mistake. But yes you need to add it to the same plsit you just said.

Comment: I found the problem. I hope one day it will help someone. Go to Project Settings -> Info -> Under the Custom iOS Target Properties section find the Required background modes and add your key here as well. I don't know why not all my plist file keys are here.

Comment: @thus you can add this as answer and accept/close the question.

Comment: @rishi I did. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. I hope one day it will help someone. Go to Project Settings -> Info -> Under the Custom iOS Target Properties section find the Required background modes and add your key here as well. I don't know why not all my plist file keys are here.

Comment: Worked. The key is that every target has it's own Info.plist file.

Comment: Where is "Project Settings" in Version 11?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Targets -> your project target -> build settings -> search for NSMotionUsageDescription

[image]